# Is it possible to Register/provision a Bot via service

Tags: botframework

I'm looking at using the Bot Framework (https://docs.botframework.com) is it possible to register a bot programmatically e.g via service? I see there are Azure bots but still don't see a way to register via service?

Comment: Would be wonderful if they make possible to register bot through service. But at the moment feature is unavailable. :/

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you have to manually log into the portal to register the bot and obtain your keys. There has not been any indication from Microsoft that this will change in future.

Answer (score 1):

from what I know about the goals of the dev team, since this is a highly requested feature, we will probably see this in action in future version of the bot framework.
But no kind of timeline yet for this feature.